# E0701: XML schema error, cvc-pattern-valid oozie error

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I am trying to run oozie workflow, but I am getting the below error:

`E0701: XML schema error, cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'mockup and mapping table update' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '([a-zA-Z_]([\-_a-zA-Z0-9])*){1,39}' for type 'IDENTIFIER'.`

I am using below regex in my query. Is something wrong with that? Everything works fine when I run through Hive or CLI.

`regexp_replace(id_col, '^0|[a-zA-Z]+$', '')`

Below is my workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="proj_map" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="sources_creation"/>
    <action name="sources_creation">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <script>/user/sin/oozie/sources_creation.hql</script>
        </hive>
        <ok to="mockup and mapping table update"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <action name="mockup and mapping table update">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <script>/user/sin/oozie/project_mapping.hql</script>
        </hive>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action name can not have white space. `<action name="mockup and mapping table update"\>`. Remove the white spaces from the action name. It should work afterwards.